# How to modify the author choices field in my generic CreateView with authors(fk) only from the current user?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-generic-views

This is my code, i have read the documentations and it seems this method is the right way, i get no errors but i see no results. Can somebody help me in what i am doing wrong?

```
class BookCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     model = Book
     fields = ['title', 'isbn', 'year', 'author', 'publisher']


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(BookCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        b = Book.objects.all
        form.instance.author = ModelChoiceField(queryset=b.author_set.filter(owner=self.request.user))
        return super(BookCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Not very sure, but shouldn't you be mentioning a `template` parameter for `create_view`?

Comment: @DeA It takes care automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to simply exclude the `author` from the list of fields, then set it in the `form_valid` method:

```
class BookCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['title', 'isbn', 'year', 'publisher']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(BookCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

If you do this, make sure you delete your second `form_valid` method, which is replacing the correct `form_valid` method above.

If you must include `author` as a field with a single option, then the code is much more complicated. You need a custom form with an `__init__` method which takes `user` and sets the queryset for the `auth` field.

Then you need to modify your view to use your custom form, and override `get_form_kwargs` to include `self.request.user`.